# Astro.js implementing auth through jwt and store

Tags: javascript, authentication, jwt, store, astrojs

I have a spring boot backend which can send jwt token on login. I need to implement these features in my Astro frontend:

- Redirect to /login if no token is found in local storage
- On login retirieve the token from server response and store it in localStorage
- if any of the requests sent to server return 401 (unauthorized) which will mean token either expired or is not correct -> delete token from localstorage and redirect to /login
- token should be sent with every request in headers: Authorization: Bearer

There is little to no documentation about this for Astro specifically. I have implemented the same thing with my old vue project using store and mutations but I did not find anything remotely simillar with astro though.. Here is the project file I was referring to: https://github.com/salat-23/wafflesproject-frontend/blob/master/src/store/index.js

P.S. I am not a front end developer and dont know a lot of things so any help and tips will be appreciated!

Comment: Did you find anything useful between Astro.request, Astro.response, and Astro.redirect()?

Comment: Update: I just discovered this PR: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/pull/6463 -- exciting!

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented Token-Based Authentication in a Astro project using [ServiceWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API).

With a ServiceWorker you will be able to create a fetch event handler that will be called for every request your frontend sends. In this handler you can redirect, add auth headers and store tokens.

Since [Astro is a Multi-page application framework](https://docs.astro.build/en/concepts/mpa-vs-spa/), this is the only solution to your problem that I know of.
Token-Based Authentication is easier to implement in a Single-page application like [NuxtJS](https://nuxtjs.org/)

[This is my ServiceWorker for a Astro project.](https://github.com/HF5-PROJECT/web/blob/master/public/serviceWorker.js)

Comment: Yep, I ended up switching to vue for this matter